# Primes of the forms $4m+1$ and $4m+3$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I ask if it is possible to demonstrate that any prime number $p$ of the form $4m+1$ can be written as $$p=q_1+2q_2=(4n_1+3)+2(4n_2+3)$$ and, conversely, that any prime number $q$ of the form $4n+3$ can be written as $$q=p_1+2p_2=(4m_1+1)+2(4m_2+1)$$
For the first primes we have:
$$3=1+2\cdot1\qquad5=-1+2\cdot3$$
$$7=5+2\cdot1\qquad13=7+2\cdot3$$
$$11=1+2\cdot5\qquad17=3+2\cdot7$$
$$19=17+2\cdot1\qquad29=7+2\cdot11$$
$$23=13+2\cdot5\qquad37=23+2\cdot7$$
Thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: If the $p_i$ and $q_i$ are supposed to be primes, then this is **very** unlikely to be proven.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to write that the set of admitted numbers includes, other than all primes, also $\pm1$. Thanks.

Comment: are you intending that $q_1, q_2, p_1, p_2$ are also prime?  (Trivial otherwise).  Of the top of me head I'd say this looks let yet another corrolary of either the Goldbach Conjecture and/or the twin prime conjecture (assuming we skip $p=5$).  I haven't actually thought it through though.

Answer (score -1):

It follows that :
$$p=(4n_1+3)+2(4n_2+3) \iff \color{#d05}{p = 4(n_1+2n_2+2)+1}$$

And

$$q=(4m_1+1)+2(4m_2+1)\iff \color{#2d0}{q = 4(m_1+2m_2)+3}$$

so , $p = 4k+1$ and $q = 4l+3$ regardless of whether $p,q$ are primes or composite.

Comment: I think you want to use the $\iff$ property instead of $\implies$